# Contact Page Acting Strange

Tags: google-analytics

In the Analytics All Pages view below, 28 people have visited our Contact-us page and spent an average of 2 minutes and 11 seconds on the page. The actual page is at https://www.sustmanufacturing.com/contact-us/ and you can see that there's nothing to do here but put in some simple information and leave a message, which is then sent to the business owner's email. I've used this page myself to send him a message and that works fine but he says he's never received a single message from a site visitor, other than me.  So what in the world are people doing on this page for 2:11 if not leaving him a message?   Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this is an average. So with just 28 visits it's possible that one person could have left up the page for 10 minutes while playing with their phones while 27 people opened the page and closed it immediately, but the *average* time would still be quite high.

It appears to be a Squarespace site so I would not look to any technical issues here, as their implementation of Google Analytics (in my experience) is sound.

Comment: Thanks.  I was surprised that you said that your experience with the Squarespace Google Analytics implementation is sound. I've had trouble. They hardcode a rel=cannonical statement that defines canonical as having a trailing slash but then they fill the sitemap with page versions that do not have a trailing slash so don't get indexed. You can see in the image above that both forms of contact-us are there, which is confusing.  If you have any experience with this I'd be happy to post a new question on it where you can perhaps clear things up.

Comment: That's a fair point, and I do thin you have identified an error there. that's more of an architecture issue though. I mean I haven't seen pages missing a GA tag, events not firing, or anything like that.